# Minimum distance in a list of vectors

Tags: python, pandas

> 1: 1 2 4
>   2: 4 5 6
>   3: 7 8 9
>   4: 0 2 5

The numbers before colon are labels for the 3-D vectors which are after the colon. I've another vector let's say (12, 13, 14). I need to find the minimum distance between this vector and the given list of vectors and then assign the label as a result. Any suggestions? I'm using pandas.

Comment: What did you try? Please add your attempts to solve the problem :)

Comment: Vectors do not have "distances" from vectors. That would be points (in a 3D euclidean space)

Comment: @AlienLifeForm we all knew what the meaning was... Arguments of semantics rarely help anyone.

Comment: @Aaron Semantics is about "meaning of" and I think it's important. (My Analytical mechanics teacher would have had me shot for saying vectors have distances). Point in case, first thing I thought was he had been given char vectors and had to look for some string distance.

Comment: @AlienLifeForm the "meaning of" varies from person to person depending on their background and experience. If I were to refer to the *texture* of a metal, colleagues of mine would inherently know I mean the distribution of size and orientation of single crystal grains. If I said it to anyone else, they might think I was talking about the surface finish. That's why **context** is more important than semantics, and in this case is perfectly clear.

Comment: My dear learned friends,  my sincerest apologies. I was working and thinking about cosine similarity of the vectors in my dataset when I posted the question and hence went on to cause this blunder. I meant points and wanted to know the minimum distance between the points in the euclidean space. Again, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.linalg.norm` to find euclidean distance

```
In [359]: p = (12, 13, 14)

In [360]: df.apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x-p), axis=1)
Out[360]:
0    18.493242
1    13.856406
2     8.660254
3    18.601075
dtype: float64

In [361]: df.apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x-p), axis=1).idxmin()
Out[361]: 2

In [363]: df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x-p), axis=1).idxmin()]
Out[363]:
x    7
y    8
z    9
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Or, you could also find distance in a shorter syntax

```
In [377]: (df-p).apply(np.linalg.norm, 1)
Out[377]:
0    18.493242
1    13.856406
2     8.660254
3    18.601075
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Maybe better to do `i = np.linalg.norm(df - p, axis=1).argmin()`. `idx = df.index[i]`. This should be orders of magnitude faster

Comment: Thanks I can make it work. One question though, I can get coordinates and and I can get the index but what if the labels were random integers or string for that matter. How do you propose getting those labels?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distance metric, of course, but something like

```
diffs = df - v
distances = diffs.pow(2).sum(axis=1).pow(.5)
return distances.idxmin()
```

should work if `v` is a list or array of the same length as the rows in `df`. This would give the Euclidean distance. You might want to do this in `numpy` for better performance. Something like:

```
diffs = arr - v
distances = (diffs ** 2).sum(axis=1) ** .5
return distances.argmin()
```

EDIT:
Borrowing from @John Galt's solution, this can be achieved in a simpler and faster way by:

```
df.index[np.linalg.norm(df - p, axis=1).argmin()]
```